# How to Round a BigDecimal Value to its nearest hundreths

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Example:

```
public class Round {

    private static final BigDecimal TWELVE = new BigDecimal("12");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal annualAmt = new BigDecimal("55867.59");
        BigDecimal monthlyAmt = null;

        monthlyAmt = annualAmt.divide(TWELVE, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(monthlyAmt);
    }
}
```

The above program output is 4656. I want to round this to the nearest hundredth as 4700.

Similarly 4235 --> 4200

Answer (score 11):

To round a given `BigDecimal` to the nearest hundred, use `monthlyAmt = monthlyAmt.setScale(-2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)` (or substitute the appropriate rounding mode).

Comment: I would add a call to `toPlainString()`, else the output is `4.7E+3`.

Comment: yes it gives exponent value.Call toPlainString() is giving type mismatch error. I want to return a bigdecimal here. monthlyAmt should be BigDecimal.

Comment: If `monthlyAmt` should be a `BigDecimal`, then the answer I gave you is correct and you shouldn't call any other methods.

Comment: I tried your step but the output is 4.7E+3, which is not the expected.

Comment: In what way?  It's the correct value.  You may just not be displaying it correctly at the other end.

Comment: monthlyAmt = annualAmt.divide(TWELVE, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).setScale(-2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); displays output as 4.7e+3. I want the output as 4700. Is there any way?

Comment: That's an error in how you display the output, not in the computation itself.  Use toPlainString when displaying the output.

Comment: @CoolSpring you can `setScale` twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177787/how-to-round-a-bigdecimal-value-to-its-nearest-hundreths/74799139#74799139

Answer (score 2):

You can `setScale` twice.

- First, `-2` to make rounding (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177787/how-to-round-a-bigdecimal-value-to-its-nearest-hundreths/30177830#30177830) answer).
- Second, `0` to set result scale you want.

```
public class Round {

    private static final BigDecimal TWELVE = new BigDecimal("12");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal annualAmt = new BigDecimal("55867.59");
        BigDecimal monthlyAmt = annualAmt.divide(TWELVE, 0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        BigDecimal monthlyAmtRounded = monthlyAmt.setScale(-2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(monthlyAmtRounded);
    }
}
```

Result is `4700`.

Second example:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("4235")
            .setScale(-2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Result is `4200`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use this rounding formula for integer calculation:

```
    res = ((number + factor - 1) / factor) * factor;
```